# SSOFilter java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

I have created sample sso wso2 program with help of existing code which I have downloaded from wso2 website and follow the same steps. But when I am executing my programm I am getting error

> SEVERE: Exception starting filter SSOFilter
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.util.SSOAgentConfigs.isSAMLSSOLoginEnabled(SSOAgentConfigs.java:345)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.util.SSOAgentConfigs.initCheck(SSOAgentConfigs.java:222)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.SSOAgentFilter.init(SSOAgentFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5546)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Thre

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: check what is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the source I referred, there isn't way of throwing NPE from that line since it have following code,

`public static boolean isSAMLSSOLoginEnabled() {
        return samlSSOLoginEnabled;
    }`

And I found this matching lines in older v1.2.0 of org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent component [1].

So in order to resolve the issue, you need to find the correct source of the relevant jar, debug the flow and need to check exactly which variable it use a null reference to access something.

If you find difficulty finding a source of a relevant component, raise a separate question mentioning the versions you are looking for.

[1] https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent/1.2.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sso/agent/util/SSOAgentConfigs.java

HTH,
DarRay

Comment: thanks for reply, I solved that problem but now I am getting org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.exception.SSOAgentException: 'LoginUrl' not configured

Comment: You could raise a new question on that; basically your app doesn't pick the config file. Giving you a general guide on SO, since you seems to be new, please put a answer if the problem is resolved by your self; since it would be helpful for the next person who face the same issue. Or accept an answer which was helpful on resolving the problem, and give any feedback if you done anything additionally.